# Error while validating HTML "document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul", "ol", "menu", "dir" start-tag"

Tags: html, wordpress, validating

So I'm trying to code something on wordpress for the first time but the validator doesn't seem to like me. Look at the error I got while validating:

Line 87, Column 33: document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul", "ol", "menu", "dir" start-tag

I've searched everywhere, I'm not aware of any missing or misplaced li or ul tags

can someone help me out on this one?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>
Blog</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 2.9.2" />
<!-- leave this for stats please -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cmc-milagro/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?feed=rss2" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" title="RSS .92" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?feed=rss" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 0.3" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?feed=atom" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://localhost/wordpress/xmlrpc.php" />
 <link rel='archives' title='March 2010' href='http://localhost/wordpress/?m=201003' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://localhost/wordpress/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 

<link rel='index' title='Blog' href='http://localhost/wordpress' />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 2.9.2" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <h1><a href="http://localhost/wordpress">
    Blog</a>
  </h1>
  Just another WordPress weblog</div>
<div id="container">
      <h2><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=8">

    Teste Post 3    </a></h2>
  <div class="post" id="post-8">
    <div class="entry">
      <p>Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce in nibh elit. Morbi lorem urna, viverra sed  blandit eget, mattis venenatis felis. Maecenas viverra pellentesque  justo, vel tincidunt massa semper sit amet. Vestibulum rhoncus purus in  mauris fermentum ut aliquet augue semper.</p>
      <p class="postmetadata">
        Filed under&#58;        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?cat=1" title="View all posts in Uncategorized" rel="category">Uncategorized</a>        by        admin        <br />

        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=8#respond" title="Comment on Teste Post 3">No Comments &#187;</a>         &#124; <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?action=edit&amp;post=8" title="Edit post">Edit</a>      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <h2><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=5">
    Teste Post 2    </a></h2>
  <div class="post" id="post-5">

    <div class="entry">
      <p>Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce in nibh elit. Morbi lorem urna, viverra sed  blandit eget, mattis venenatis felis. Maecenas viverra pellentesque  justo, vel tincidunt massa semper sit amet. Vestibulum rhoncus purus in  mauris fermentum ut aliquet augue semper. Duis orci metus, cursus ac  tempor eget, faucibus vel elit. Sed rutrum mollis posuere. Maecenas  luctus commodo augue vel fringilla. Nunc enim lacus, varius nec tempor  sed, congue vel elit. Suspendisse urna ligula, pharetra ac malesuada  quis, scelerisque eget justo.</p>
      <p class="postmetadata">
        Filed under&#58;        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?cat=1" title="View all posts in Uncategorized" rel="category">Uncategorized</a>        by        admin        <br />
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=5#respond" title="Comment on Teste Post 2">No Comments &#187;</a>         &#124; <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?action=edit&amp;post=5" title="Edit post">Edit</a>      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
    <h2><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=3">
    Teste Post 1    </a></h2>
  <div class="post" id="post-3">
    <div class="entry">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ut mattis  elit. In sed nulla lobortis dolor pellentesque fringilla at eget ipsum.  Proin pellentesque vehicula ultricies. Phasellus velit nunc, tempus nec  scelerisque vel, euismod pellentesque diam. Vivamus consectetur, sapien  sit amet rhoncus porta, sapien nisl imperdiet diam, dapibus placerat  sem ante condimentum nisl. Nulla facilisi. Mauris eu turpis mauris. Nunc  at turpis elit, et mattis purus. Proin varius, nunc rhoncus consectetur  dignissim, lacus augue accumsan sem, nec pretium magna est a massa.  Duis eu justo arcu. Curabitur diam ligula, semper non blandit ut,  sodales ac dui.</p>
      <p class="postmetadata">

        Filed under&#58;        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?cat=1" title="View all posts in Uncategorized" rel="category">Uncategorized</a>        by        admin        <br />
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=3#respond" title="Comment on Teste Post 1">No Comments &#187;</a>         &#124; <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?action=edit&amp;post=3" title="Edit post">Edit</a>      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

    <h2><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=1">
    Hello world!    </a></h2>
  <div class="post" id="post-1">
    <div class="entry">
      <p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!</p>
      <p class="postmetadata">
        Filed under&#58;        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?cat=1" title="View all posts in Uncategorized" rel="category">Uncategorized</a>        by        admin        <br />

        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=1#comments" title="Comment on Hello world!">1 Comment &#187;</a>         &#124; <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?action=edit&amp;post=1" title="Edit post">Edit</a>      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="navigation">
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
      <li id="search">
      <form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://localhost/wordpress/">
<div>
 <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" size="15" /><br />
 <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</div>
</form>      <li class="pagenav"><h2>Pages</h2><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2" title="About">About</a></li>

</ul></li>    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>
        Categories      </h2>
      <ul>
         <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?cat=1" title="View all posts filed under Uncategorized">Uncategorized</a> (4)
</li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>
        Archives      </h2>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='http://localhost/wordpress/?m=201003' title='March 2010'>March 2010</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

      <li id="linkcat-2" class="linkcat"><h2>Blogroll</h2>
 <ul>
<li><a href="http://wordpress.org/development/">Development Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/">Documentation</a></li>
<li><a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/">Plugins</a></li>
<li><a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/">Suggest Ideas</a></li>
<li><a href="http://wordpress.org/support/">Support Forum</a></li>
<li><a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/">Themes</a></li>

<li><a href="http://planet.wordpress.org/">WordPress Planet</a></li>

 </ul>
</li>
    <li>
      <h2>
        Meta      </h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/">Site Admin</a></li>        <li>

          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;_wpnonce=ee45c3c988">Log out</a>        </li>
              </ul>
    </li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<p>
Copyright &#169; 2010 Blog</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use an editor that can automatically properly space out your elements, and has folding/collapsing capability.  This would make these kinds of errors easier to find.

Answer (score 3):

Line 87:

```
</form>      <li class="pagenav"><h2>Pages</h2><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2" title="About">About</a></li>
```

The `<form></form>` that ends here is inside an `<li>` that begins 6 lines above (line 81).  That `<li>` has not been closed when the new `<li>` on line 87 is opened.

Inserting a `</li>` after `</form>` should fix it.

Comment: You probably also need to end the `<ul>` before you start the next one. Unless you intend to have a list in a list.

Answer (score 0):

The `<li class="pagenav"><h2>Pages</h2>` needs to be ***directly*** inside an `<ul>` tag.

```
<ul>
<li id="search">

<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://localhost/wordpress/">
<div>
 <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" size="15" /><br />
 <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</div>
</form>      

<li class="pagenav"><h2>Pages</h2>

<ul>
  <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2" title="About">About</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: It **is** inside an **li** tag!

Comment: To put more accurately, you forgot to end the li tag with `</li>`.  Just put `</li>` right after `</form>` and you're good to go.

Comment: You are absolutely right, fixed my mistake and updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li>blah
    <form>....</form>
    <li>...
```

The end tag for the first list item is missing. So you are trying to create a list item as a child of another list item.

This would be fine in HTML, but in XHTML all elements must be explicitly closed.

You probably intended to have this construct:

```
<ul>
    <li>blah
    <form>....</form>
    </li>
    <li>...
```